# Getting Url params in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on reset password feature using nodejs & expressjs. When user clicking the reset mail URL,he will redirect to a controller with some encrypted data.

```
router.get('/:encryptedData',controller.resetPassword);
```

In this page i am able to access the req.params.encryptedData and when he submit the reset form,it will post to

```
localhost:3000/reset/0183d5992d2c79743d40ea2de6e60f8ffd4c8bb996f3d46971
```

and the post router is like this

```
router.post('/:encryptedData',controller.postreset);
```

inside the controller i tried to access 'encryptedData' using req.params.encryptedData , but it showing 'reset' in console.Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Your router seems to configured the right way, it should be something like `router.post('/reset/:encryptedData',controller.postreset);`

Answer (score 0):

Since, your route is:
`localhost:3000/reset/0183d5992d2c79743d40ea2de6e60f8ffd4c8bb996f3d46971`,

the post router should look like:

`router.post('/reset/:encryptedData',controller.postreset);`

Ideally, configuration should look like:

```
var app = express();

var router = express.Router();
var resetRouter = express.Router();

// you can nest routers by attaching them as middleware:
router.use('/reset', resetRouter);

app.use('/', router);
```

Comment: app.use('/reset',require('./resetpassword')); line added in server.js page. So it is not necessary to add /reset in url , right ?

Comment: If `resetpassword.js` exports a router instance, then it is fine.

Comment: resetpassword is a folder location which contains controller.js , index.js , password.html.

Comment: express router doesn't work that way. Check the answer above. I have added config for how to nest routes.